# Changing the contents of an input/div/span etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add a .listen class to various elements on my page, could be a button, could be an input, div, span etc.

```
$('.listen').on('click', this._init.bind(this));
```

In the method I wish to replace text in the element that was clicked.

```
p._init = function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).val('new data');
};
```

The above works for input elements, but not for things like divs. Is there a way to change the data on any type of elements or will I have to use a switch to test for the variations?

Comment: A DIV doesn't have a value, so it will never work on a DIV.

Comment: Yes - that's what Im asking, I know val wont work on a div

Comment: `.text()` will work on a div. Be careful, if you have a `div` that contains DOM elements that function can override it

Comment: You can use `e.currentTarget.tagName` to get the type of element, and then switch to `text()` instead of `val()` etc ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get a little fancy and check if the element has a `value` property, and change methods based one that, something like

```
p._init = function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget)['value' in e.currentTarget ? 'val' : 'text']('new data');
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GTxA7/)

Unless you're adding value properties to elements that don't natively have value properties, that should work.

Comment: @panthro - Works either way for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GTxA7/1/, and it should, as the input elements have a value property by default

Comment: Further testing shows this even clearer, some elements have value properties, others don't -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/A6p7p/

Answer (score 0):

For input it's val() for divs and stuff it's text().

If you wanna do everything with a single event, you can do something like:

```
$('.listen').on(...
{
    if($(this).is('input')) 
    { 
        use val() 
    }
    else
    {
       use text()
    }
}
```

Comment: So will I need a switch statement to test input type?

Comment: Something like that, yes. I would use jQuery's .is()

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fx7ug/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     _init = function(e){ 
       if(e.target.nodeName=='SPAN'||e.target.nodeName=='DIV')
           $(this).text('new data');
       else if(e.target.nodeName=='INPUT')
          $(this).val('new data');
      };
   $('.listen').on('click', _init);

 });
```